# Processing JMeter WebSocket Sampler's response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, websocket, jmeter

I am a novice at programming and having necessity to write program for doing load testing with JMeter, since I cannot find the existing GUI tool to perform what I want to do.

I am trying to load test an WebSocket application by using JMeter plugin “[JMeter WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/blob/master/README.md)”.

I need advise how I should process the messages sent from the WebSocket server.

Here are some conditions.

1. After establish the connection with a WebSocket server, server sends JMeter messages in an arbitrary timing.
2. When JMeter receives a message, it has to return message to notify the message is received.
3. Based on a message contents from the server, JMeter has to modify local variables.

Here is my current JMeter configuration overview.

1. Use [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) to divide thread for receiving message and sending message.
2. In receiving message thread, I tried to use [JSR223 Listner](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) under empty WebSocket sampler to write JavaScript to process the received data. Server sends the data in JSON format.
3. On sending message thread, I use While Loop controller, which will wait until variable value to be changed, in receiving message thread, based on server's message.

For example, when server sends a message "Event_A_Notify" to JMeter, receiving message thread check and set Event variable to "A". Then, sending message thread will send "Event_A_Received" to the server.

The part I'm having problem is how to handle the received messages.

In JSR223 Lisner, I can use [sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) method to retrieve the messages from WebSocket server in string format.

Here is a what the data looks like. (I modified the content to make it look simple. Actual message content is larger with more property).

```
[Message 1]
{"Sample1":"A","uuid":"a5c77959-0284-40eb-9523-8706c947b620"}

[Message 2]
{"Sample2":"B","uuid":"93330fff-13fe-4040-9fe7-0e6d7054ee4a"}    

[Message 3]
{"Sample3":"C","uuid":"099cea81-6f8f-4417-b0c5-29199f42a6f3"}    

[Message 4]
{"Sample4":"D","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a1"}
```

When the received message exceeds 10, JMeter removes the older message to keep the 10 most recent messages.

```
[Message 8]
{"Sample8":"H","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a1"} 

[Message 9]
{"Sample9":"I","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a2"} 

[Message 10]
{"Sample10":"J","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a3"} 

[Message 11]
{"Sample11":"K","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a4"} 

[Message 12]
{"Sample12":"L","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a5"} 

[Message 13]
{"Sample13":"M","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a6"} 

[Message 14]
{"Sample14":"N","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a7"} 

[Message 15]
{"Sample15":"O","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a8"} 

[Message 16]
{"Sample16":"P","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a508a9"} 

[Message 17]
{"Sample17":"Q","uuid":"01bf3c23-87cb-41cb-ab04-1a9613a50810"}
```

Here is the contents of JSR223 Listner to process the received message.

Basically, I do followings.

1. Use *sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();* to retrieve the response.
2. Use *String(responseData).split(/[Message [0-9]+]/);* and to split the string into array of messages by removing [Message \d].
3. Use array object messageArray to store all the response from the WebSocket server. And process one by one in the for loop.

> ```
> var responseData = sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
>
> var counter = parseInt(vars.get("counter1"));
>
> var messageList = new String(responseData).split(/\[Message [0-9]+\]/);
>
> messageList.shift();
>
> var messageArray = vars.getObject("messageArray");
>
> messageList.forEach(function(message, index) {
>     if (messageArray.indexOf(message) >= 0) {
>      return true;
>   }
>   else {
>      messageArray.push(message);
>   }
> });
>
> for (i = counter; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
>
>     if (messageArray[i].match(/(someEvent).*/)) {
>          vars.put("userVariable",true);
>        counter += 1;
>        break;
>    }
>    else {
>           vars.put("userVariable",false);
>       counter += 1;
>    }
> }
>
> vars.put("counter1",counter);
> vars.putObject("messageArray", messageArray);
> ```

The problem with this code are:

1. Since the messageArray object stores all messages, messageArray becomes too large and JMeter will crash eventually by OutOfMemory exception.
2. The code to check if the received message exists in the messageArray is too slow, and performance decline exponentially as the number of messages stored increases.

Could someone please adivse the more efficient and smarter way to handle WebSocket messages in the JMeter?

I really appreciate your input.

Thanks,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

> After establish the connection with a WebSocket server, server sends
>   JMeter messages in an arbitrary timing. When JMeter receives a
>   message, it has to return message to notify the message is received.
>   Based on a message contents from the server, JMeter has to modify
>   local variables.

This is quite simple to achieve with this plugin: https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/.
It provides a "read sampler" which you can use to wait for a message, than extract anything you need from the received message and use "write sampler" to return a message to the server.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the comment. The problem with this approach is that my environment requires communicating with 2 WebSocket servers, and "read sampler" can use only 1 connection per thread. So I'm using "WebSocket Sampler" which allows multiple WebSocket connections per thread.

Comment: Hi Ken, Seems you've solved it in the meantime.... still i'd like to add that support for multiple connections is in development and although it's not completely finished yet, it should work. Just checkout the https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/branch/multiple-connections branch. If you'd run into trouble with this branch, just file an issue in the git repo and i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

Basically following is what I decided to do and seems to work much better now.

1. Extract message index and contents, then assign to JavaScript object's key value pair.
2. Once the message is processed, remove the message index and the message contents from the JavaScript object.
3. User counter variable to keep track of the most recent processed message index.

> ```
> // Retrieve response data from websocket server
> var responseData = sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
>
> // Retrieve counter
> var counter = parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
>
>
> // Store index of message in to array meessageIndexArray
> var re = new RegExp(/\[Message ([0-9]+)\]/g);
> var messageIndex = []
> var match;
> while (match = re.exec(responseData)) {
>    messageIndex.push(parseInt(match[1]));
> }
>
> // Get the message List and remove [Message \d] field and new line.
> var messageList = new String(responseData).split(/\[Message [0-9]+\]/);
> messageList.shift();
>
> // If counter value is less than the minimum number of the messageIndex,
> // set the counter to messageIndex[0]
>
> if (counter < messageIndex[0]) {
>    counter = messageIndex[0];
> }
>
> // Figure out the index of the counter value in the messageIndex
> var counterIndex = messageIndex.indexOf(counter);
>
>
> // Put all of the messages into messageObject object with messageIndex as a key and messageList as a value
> var messageObject = vars.getObject("messageObject");
>
> if (counterIndex != -1) {
>   for (i = counterIndex; i < messageIndex.length; i ++) {
>      messageObject[messageIndex[i]] = messageList[i];
>   }
>
>   // Iterate through messageObject properties to check message
>   for (var prop in messageObject) {
>       if (messageObject[prop].match(/(SomeValue).*/)) {
>          vars.put("userVariable",value1);
>             ..
>           delete messageObject[prop];
>           counter += 1;
>           break;
>           }
>       else {
>           vars.put("userVariable",value2);
>           delete messageObject[prop];
>           counter += 1;
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> vars.put("counter",counter);
> vars.putObject("messageObject", messageObject);
> ```